# Regex - Match sequence between lines that depend previous value

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I tried make a regex to get inside "Miles" tag but only for the "Product1", but the most near that I arrived was this

```
(?<=<Product>Product1)[](?<=<Miles>)[\d\D]*?(?=<\/Miles>)

<ProductList>
    <Product>Product1</Product>
    <Dot/>
    <Miles>200</Miles>

    <Product>Product2</Product>
    <Dot/>
    <Miles>200</Miles>
</ProductList>
```

I don't know how can I take away the previous part before '' from the result.

Test: https://regex101.com/r/wU0iZ0/4

The application I'm using is notepad++

Comment: From the regex tag: "NOTE: Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead."

Comment: Is your format always exactly like that, with those indentations and newlines exactly where they are?

Comment: You have tagged your question with [regex] and [xml].  Your input is very much XML like.  You should *seriously* consider using XPath instead of regex for your purpose.

Comment: @Happy you're probably right, but not necessarily: There are situations that allow regex but not xpath (eg haproxy)

Comment: If you use a SAX parser for tag and content, whenever you get the <Product> tag, look for Product1 content. Set a flag, look for <Miles> tag, look for next content. Reset the flag if not the sequence expected.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but actually I want make this in regex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This regex captures the content before miles for a given product in group 1, and the replacement puts in a new value. For example, to replace the miles for `Product2` with `666`:

```
Find: (<Product>Product2([\d\D](?!<Product>))*<Miles>)\d*
Repl: ${1}666
```

The curly brackets around the group number are needed to disambiguate the group number.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/m6DO6LatO8) of the regex in action.

Comment: Hy Bohemian, I don't know why, but only your first and last expression work on your live demo, in notepad++ is not work (Sorry i didnt mention the application before)

Comment: @MichelSouza I'll look into it, but first... what do you want to do? Replace miles? Delete everything but miles? Something else? What you want changes the answer, especially with notepad which has some strange behaviours not seen elsewhere. Let me know.

Comment: I will use this to make a replace and a simple search, a search just is ok, but the replace gets everything between the 'Product1' and 'Miles', this XML is just a exemplo, there a lot of tags more then this.
Thank You so much for help

Comment: I want do this in notepad++ not for me, but the other team members that need something fast and simple to show the sequence, how they dont use  so much and dont have any other tool to simplify this activity

Comment: The main idea is replace the number 200 miles

Comment: @MichelSouza I've tested my answer (slightly modified, but essentially the same) in notepad++ and it works